# Know the way to last re-start a database Server

Tags: sql-server

Is their any way to know the last server re-start is physical like proper shutdown and then switch on or just re-start like start and re-start?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Windows event log, it will tell you all the times the sql server restarted, as well as when the OS was restarted.  Based on those two events and their respective dates, you will be able to figure out what triggered what.